# Internal Server Error 500 status code while trying to access endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

Hello I am a beginner at Spring Boot and have been trying to work through a 500 error when trying to access an endpoint. I do have data in an mysql database that I am trying to fetch.

Here is an example of the Entity I am trying to get.

```
package com.example.demo.Entities;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "vacations")
public class Vacation {        
    @Id    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)    
    @Column(name="vacation_id")    
    private Long id;    

    @Column(name = "vacation_title")    
    private String vacation_title;    

    @Column(name  = "description")    
    private String description;    

    @Column(name = "travel_price")    
    private BigDecimal travel_price;    

    @Column(name = "image_url")    
    private String image_URL;    

    @Column(name = "create_date")    
    @CreationTimestamp    
    private Date create_date;    

    @Column(name = "last_update")    
    @UpdateTimestamp    
    private Date last_update;        

    @OneToMany    
    private Set<Excursion> excursions;        

    public Vacation() {}
    }
```

Here is the the JpaRepository:

```
package com.example.demo.DAO;
import com.example.demo.Entities.Vacation;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@Repository
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface VacationRepository extends JpaRepository<Vacation, Long> {    }
```

I can run localhost:8080/api and that will work just fine showing verything past /api but when I do api/vacations it return an error 500. Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add the stack trace.

Comment: did you look in the log files?

Comment: did you create the RestController for the `Vacation` Entity you wanted?